# Merging linestrings in QGIS using PostgreSQL and PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, merge, linestring

I've to merge all linestrings from a PostgreSQL table "river" where not more than two start-/endpoints are overlapping. In the illustration below I use a "M" to mark all linestrings that needs to be merged.

[image]
Unfortunately I'm new to PostGIS. To my knowledge QGIS needs an id (gid) and a geometry (geom) column to load a table or view. But I'm not sure which PostGIS function will do the job. Can anyone please help me with the SQL query?

Comment: There is not, directly. ST_Union will combine all intersecting geometries, but you will need to build a list of all linestrings with only one intersection on each end, which you can get via ST_StartPoint and ST_EndPoint and a count of the intersections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `ST_LineMerge()` function http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_LineMerge.html

You could try to serve all your rivers network as one MultiLineString `ST_LineMerge(ST_Multi(St_Collect(geometry)))` The result is also a MultiLineString with segments sewed together. So after `ST_LineMerge()` you could get sewed segments via `ST_Dump()`.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW river_merge AS
SELECT
row_number() over() AS gid,
g.*
FROM
(SELECT
(ST_Dump(ST_LineMerge(ST_Multi(St_Collect(geom))))).geom::geometry(linestring, SRID) AS geom
FROM river)
AS g;`

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but it might give you what you want. With `intersections` you get those ids and geometries that intersect with others. And the `SELECT` statement will `ST_Union` all of these records that intersect exactly with two other geometries. `ST_Dump` makes sure you don't get MultiLinestrings as a result.

```
WITH intersections AS (
    SELECT
        l1.id,
        l1.wkb_geometry
        COUNT(1)
    FROM
        lines l1
    JOIN
        lines l2 ON
        ST_Intersects(l1.wkb_geometry, l2.wkb_geometry) AND
        l1.id <> l2.id
    GROUP BY
        l1.id,
        l1.wkb_geometry
)

SELECT
    ST_Dump(ST_Union(i.wkb_geometry)).geom wkb_geometry
FROM
    intersections i
WHERE
    count = 2
;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't unterstand this. There is only one PostGIS table: `CREATE TABLE river
(gid serial NOT NULL,
geom geometry(linestring, SRID),
CONSTRAINT river_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid));`

Comment: ok, so replace my lines table with your river table and my columns with your columns.