# How to reconstruct a network with multipart edges to a network with singlepart edges

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, network

I have a network shapefile that between its vertices , there are edges that have multiple geometric objects. When I try to node it in postgis, it creates multiple segments in the database that topologically are actually one single edge.To clarify, imagine from node A to node B, I have one edge. In the database, this topologically one edge, has been divided into multiple segments and saved in the database. Could someone please let me know how I could reconstruct the network to have a network with singlepart edges in ArcGIS-Desktop or using any other tool?

Comment: You tagged ArcGIS but do not mention that in your question so I have removed it, because also note you should use ArcGIS-Desktop, not just ArcGIS. Can you confirm you are working with ArcGIS? When you say multiple edges, do you mean you have multipart lines, or that there are multiple lines stacked on top of each other for the same edge but they are separate records? I'm pretty sure tools exist in PostGIS, but I could only address those specific to Arc. There are solutions to both multiparts-to-singleparts/explode and with proper license level topology checks to correct stacked objects.

Comment: I am working with both ArcGIS-Desktop and PostGIS. With saying multiple edges,database-wise, I mean there are multiple records for a topologically one edge (ARC).  To make it clearer, I used pgr_nodenetwork and pgr_createTopology to create a topologically-right graph. It did work in terms of creating nodes in right position. However, each graph still consists of multiple records in the database. Also, I have tried multiparts-to-singleparts in ArcGIS-Desktop that did not what I needed to do.

Comment: Have you got topologically equals edges. If so have you tried to add `distinct` predicate over edges geometries?

Comment: I am not sure if I truly understand you when saying topologically equal edge? But to clarify, imagine from node A to node B, I have one edge. In the database, this topologically one edge, has been divided into multiple segments and saved in the database. I think I need to edit the post to reflect it better.

Comment: Although I finally ended up using dissolve in ArcMAP to deal with this issue, still happy to hear from any solution someone may have.

Comment: If I get your comments right, you have `A B` edge splitted into `A c d e B` edge, and you want to merge edges of that web into single geometry. If so, you have situation similar to this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147316/merging-linestrings-in-qgis-using-postgresql-and-postgis

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Those are sometimes known as [pseudo-nodes](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99566/). There's a few questions here on getting rid of them, and dissolve is one option/step in doing so. Sometimes dissolving results in crossing lines that aren't desired, so you have to Planarize or use the unsplit lines option. There are also some Topology checks in ArcGIS you can run for them if you have the right license level.You can always post your solution as an answer - answering your own question is perfectly ok.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to make what you are asking clearer, please?  There appears to have been considerable advice already offered as comments that should help you to do this.